# What's the meaning of "be it" used in this sentence below?

Tags: phrase-meaning, subjunctives

> "My happiness comes from women, **be it** my mother, someone who had me in her womb for 9 months, then had to deal with my behavior for 13 more years, **be it** my sisters who have supported me and tried their best to make me happy"

Comment: **be it** is like "whether it be", a kind of conditional. The word order is inverted and the verb goes from "is" to "be" as a marker. You could paraphrase: Whether it is my mother, or my sisters, from whom my happiness comes, in either case my happiness comes from women.  P.S.  Did you mean to say **sisters** in the plural? If not, change "their" to "her" and "have" to "has".

Comment: Were this anything other than plain old ***subjunctive inversion***, we would have told you so. :)

Comment: What @TRomano said. Note that the cited usage is at the very least "clumsy" (if not actually "ungrammatical"), in that the second instance of ***be it*** should more naturally be replaced by ***or***. I think it suggests a somewhat precocious 13-year-old attempting with limited success to use a relatively formal and dated "literary" style/register.

Comment: I would recommend omitting **someone**.

Comment: be it A or be it B. I hate apples, be they green or red.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo would you please tell me what 'it' indicates in the sentence?

Comment: @Evariste Galois: I think a contemporary linguist/grammarian would say that **it** is so-called "expletive 'it' " used with an extraposed subject, "my mother": *It is my mother* in the declarative becomes *if it be my mother* or *be it my mother* in the subjunctive.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo the it looks like this it as in "it is raining now!" Then, doesn't it indicate anything?

Comment: @Evariste Galois:  That is correct, so-called "expletive" or "dummy" **it** does not have a specific referent.

Answer (score 7):

"be it" is like "Whether it is" to introduce lists or alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

It's a present subjunctive inversion of "whether it be".  "Whether it be" means "if it be this or if it not be this".

Comment: `whether it be` is not correct to me!

Comment: @Abbasi It _is_ correct. “Subjunctive mood.”